# Cannot regist intended password salt value by keycloak admin api

Tags: keycloak

I tried to add user to keycloak 3.4.3.Final by admin api with json file like this.

Command

```
bin\kcadm.bat create users -r master -f add-user.json
```

add-user.json Content

```
{
    "username" : "myUserName",
    "enabled" : true,
    "credentials" : [ {
        "type" : "password",
        "hashedSaltedValue" : "encoded password string",
        "salt" : "salt string",
        "hashIterations" : 27500,
        "algorithm" : "pbkdf2-sha256"
     } ],
    "realmRoles" : [ "admin" ]
}
```

Salt value was not registered as it was written in the json file. 
For example, when use [published test data](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/1aeec2a83c6677cd7dcfccb6ba2c39d10143b920/testsuite/integration-arquillian/tests/base/src/test/resources/keycloak-add-user.json), salt value "3fBAt5GAGGxFrV9fznpZHQ==" was registed as "ddf040b79180186c45ad5f5fce7a591d" on database.
How can I register my intended salt value?

Answer (score 1):

The above problem was solved. Sorry for lack of verification.
I should write salt byte value base64 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering how to get the base64 encoded do the following:

```
echo -n 'the_value' | openssl base64
```

you get your salt based64 encoded and you can copy that and put in the JSON.